# Upgrade to Hibernate4 and @ElementCollection results in inability to lookup existing data

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, h2

We have a model class `User` that had a `List<String>` of permissions, like so:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@CollectionOfElements
@Column()
private List<String> permissions = Collections.emptyList();
```

It produced a SQL table with an entry like the following:

[image: User permissions before H4 upgrade]

We recently upgraded to Hibernate 4, and as the `@CollectionOfElements` annotation has gone from deprecated to completely removed, we figured this was a good time to move over to `@ElementCollection`, like so:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@ElementCollection // << CHANGED
@Column()
private List<String> permissions = Collections.emptyList();
```

Upon launching, however, we were unable to log in with our *administrative* account. Curious, we examined the database using H2's JAR, and found the table had been altered:

[image: User permissions after]

**My questions:**

1. Is there a comprehensive list of the DDL/schema changes from the old `@CollectionOfElements` to the new `@ElementCollection`?
2. Is there a recommended practice, or additional annotation I can provide to these properties, that will ensure backwards compatibility? (Can I specify a specific name-mapping scheme or column name?)
3. Finally, I assume all `Collection` types will be affected by this change - `Sets`, `Maps`, etc. I just want to ensure that we don't leave any data behind, or stone unturned, during our upgrade.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First question:

I don't know of any. But the JPA specification is freely available and describes what the default table and column names are.

Second question:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name = "USER_PERMISSIONS"
                 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID"))
@Column(name = "ELEMENT")
private List<String> permissions = Collections.emptyList();
```

I personally always specify the table and column names. It avoids this kind of surprise, allows me to always choose the names that I want, and is self-documentary. And I also prefer creating the database schema and DDL by myself. This ensures that all required indices, constraints, comments, etc. are created correctly.

Third question: Yes, the nature of the collection doesn't matter. See the answer to your second question to avoid these kinds of problems.

Comment: In newer versions of hibernate and jpa, you can swap CollectionTable for JoinTable with no ill effects as far as I've seen.

Comment: Just as additional info: If you upgrade a `Map` from `@CollectionOfElements` to `@ElementCollection`, you might also need to specify a [@MapKeyColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/MapKeyColumn.html) to access the old schema.